# Why is java.lang.Void not Serializable?

Tags: java, void

It is possible to serialize the primitive 'void' per default, why does not the object 'Void' extend Serializable?

**Added example:**

The RootImplementation will have a compilation error saying "Void is not within its bound" since it does not extend Serializable.
Though would 'someMethod' be declared with 'void' it would be no problem.

```
public interface Root<R extends Serializable> extends Serializable {
  R someMethod();
}

public class RootImplementation implements Root<Void> {
  public Void someMethod() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a primitive void. And Void never has an instance, and I can't think of a use case where it would be a field on a class. But if it is, you can always make it transient, as it will always be null anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is possible to serialize the primitive 'void' per default"? There's no data to serialize... can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Jon Skeet can serialize `void`!

Comment: You **can** serialize Void, mostly b/c you can't have an instance of the Class (Constructor.setAccessible(true) and Unsafe.allocateInstance(Void.class) don't count)

Comment: Side note: serializable is meant to be an implicit/tagging interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, in response to your example, no if you changed the method to `void` it would not work, as the method has to have a return type (even if Java now allows covariant return types in overridden methods). The discussion of `void` confuses the issue.

What you want to do is declare a type parameter as a "will just return null." Void is generally a good choice for that, but for Void to work, the return type has to be Object. Void can't implement every interface in the API just because someone might want to use it to indicate a null return on a type parameter.

There are three ways to look at your problem:

1. Serializable is an overly restrictive type declaration. You should really be using Object. Do you really need it to be Serializable?
2. You can just declare the type parameter as Serializable, and in practice return null. This dosn't fully indicate that you are returning null every time, but it may be enough.
3. You can declare your own class called Null which implements Serializable, perhaps as a static nested class of the Root interface, and use that as the type parameter in this case. You will find making your own Null object is not that uncommon, even in the standard JDK there is (a private) one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

1. As ColinD mentions; most just strip the Serialziable of the generic type since the class declaration itself implies not to save not-Serializable objects on the implementation. Though as quite a few people are going to use the interface and make implementations, I want it to be as helpful as possible to not make an error.
2. I don't want eventual extension to be able to return anything else than void (or null in this case since Void must be used).
3. This is how I have done at the moment, though I wanted to ask the question and see if anyone had a better solution.

Comment: @Tomas Forsman, a class implementing serializable doesn't mean it can be serialized. Consider this: `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputSteam out){throw new NotSerializableException(getClass().getName());}` I do use that to make sure some extended classes never reach serialization form.

Answer (score 4):

The javadoc is clear:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable
>   placeholder class to hold a reference
>   to the Class object representing the
>   Java keyword

Because you can not use it, it does not need to be Serializable (except reflection stuff).

---

And for the second question: void != Void  (if you are think about != in a not java expression)

Yes `void` is a keyword and `Void` a class.

Answer (score 2):

I will put it here as comminity-wiki

Thou can (de)serialize `java.lang.Void` b/c you can initialize it with null only. Java doesn't care if a class implements `java.io.Serializable` if it's `null`.

Result of the code

```
t1.VoidOut@19821f
t1.VoidOut@c17164
```

---

```
  public class VoidOut implements java.io.Serializable{
    int x=1;
    Void v = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{
        VoidOut v = new VoidOut();
        System.out.println(v);
        ByteArrayOutputStream b =new ByteArrayOutputStream(256);
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(v);
        o.close();
        ObjectInputStream in =new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b.toByteArray()));
        System.out.println(in.readObject());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To quote the Javadocs:

> The Void class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void.

Since the class is uninstantiable, it cannot be deserialized. Ergo no need for serialization support.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to serialize the
>   primitive 'void' per default, why does
>   not the object 'Void' extend
>   Serializable?

Void doesn't carry a value, hence it makes no sense to serialize it.

> Doesn't this mean that void != Void ?

True, just as int != Integer. But when you serialize and deserialize two ints, newint==oldint (I mean `int`, not `Integer`!!!). No such construct would be possible with `void`. It just doesn't make any sense to serialize nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be only useful if you had a field of type Void, which really makes no sense. You'd also need to actually assign it an instance, which again makes no sense. As long as you don't do it, you can serialize the instance of class containing the Void field. In order to create an instance of Void, you need to use reflection in order to use the private constructor.

```
public class VoidSerializerDemo implements Serializable {
    private Void v;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final VoidSerializerDemo instance = new VoidSerializerDemo();
        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(instance);
        System.out.println("OK: null works");
        final Constructor<Void> constructor = Void.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        instance.v = constructor.newInstance();
        oos.reset();
        System.out.println("Going to throw");
        oos.writeObject(instance);
    }
}
```

So it's extremely improbably you ever need to care about the serializability of Void, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained why it doesn't make sense for a type that can never be instantiated to implement `Serializable` and why `void` isn't a primitive or serializable.

To address the code in your edit, I think you should just change the `R extends Serializable` bound to just `R`. Most generic types that are `Serializable` do not require that their type parameters be `Serializable`... they simply state that if you put something in them that isn't serializable, they won't be serializable either. This is generally a good practice, as trying too hard to enforce serializability at the compiler level can bite you  (as you see here).

Answer (score 0):

`Void` is only intended to show that a method can only return `null`, sadly there is no way to declare the null-type directly. For the jvm Void is only a normal class extending Object and as such cannot be used in place for other classes or interfaces, this makes Void for your example useless.

Since your method wont return anything but null you could replace Void with something like the following:

```
public final SerializebaleVoid extends Object implements Serializeable{
    private SerializeableVoid(){}
}
```

As to calling void a primitive, void shows the absence of a value, a method returning void does not return a value of type void instead it literally does not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache commons library, there's a org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils.Null which does extend Serializable.